# Radio button grouping with glade

Tags: glade, gtk2hs

I am programming a GUI in Haskell using the editor Glade with the gtk2hs bindings. Currently I am failing miserably at grouping the radio buttons. It will not let me select the group name. Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps:

- select the desired radio button
- click the *...* button near the *Group* entry
- *Choose a Radio Button in this project* dialog

  - select the desired row in *Objects* list
  - click the radio button at the left side of the row (it will be check)
  - press *OK* button

Answer (score 3):

Slight more accurate / up to date, for each radio button in a group, *except* the one that you want to be initially active,

1. select the (not to be initially active) radio button,
2. under "Button Attributes" in the *Group:* field, enter the ID of the initially active radio button in this group (or click on the edit icon on the right and select it in the popup list by clicking on the radio button left of its name).
3. Click OK.

Repeat for all initially not active radio buttons that should be linked to the initially active one. Note that later you can change the initially active one by simply making a radiobutton *Active* by checking the Active Checkbox under "Button Attributes". If it is already marked active, first unmark it.